# Memory leak with CreateTexture2D

Tags: windows, c++11, directx-11

I take a dx11 frame, convert it to a cv mat and put it on a ecal message buffer. Profiling shows memory balloning at CreateTexture2D.

I've tried releasing the texture, the device the context. Tried flushing the context. I put everything in a method and I thought that's suppose to allow it to deconstruct. I've tried com ptrs, and maybe I'm doing it wrong, but it has the same effect.

There's noise in this snippet, just because I've been trying everything. This whole dx11 space sucks. What am I supposed to do to get these things to actually release? Is there a way to brute force them to free the memory?

```
            flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder builder(1024);
            D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc;

            surfaceTexture->GetDesc(&desc);

            D3D11_BOX my_box;
            cv::Mat mat;
            ID3D11Texture2D* myText;

            my_box.front = 0;
            my_box.back = 1;
            my_box.left = 1600;
            my_box.top = 480;
            my_box.right = 2240;
            my_box.bottom = -160;

            desc.Width = 640;
            desc.Height = 640;
            desc.ArraySize = 1;
            desc.BindFlags = 0;
            desc.MiscFlags = 0;
            desc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
            desc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
            desc.MipLevels = 1;
            desc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ;
            desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING;
            auto d3dDevice2 = GetDXGIInterfaceFromObject<ID3D11Device>(m_device2);
            d3dDevice2->GetImmediateContext(m_d3dContext2.put());
            d3dDevice2->CreateTexture2D(&desc, NULL, &myText);
            m_d3dContext2->CopySubresourceRegion(myText, D3D11CalcSubresource(0, 0, 1), 0, 0, 0, surfaceTexture.get(), 0, &my_box);
            /*cv::directx::convertFromD3D11Texture2D(myText, mat);*/
            d3dDevice2->Release();
            m_d3dContext2->Flush();
            m_d3dContext1->Flush();
            m_d3dContext2->Release();
            m_d3dContext2.get()->Flush();
            m_d3dContext1.get()->Flush();
            m_d3dContext2.get()->Release();

           
            cv::cvtColor(mat, mat, cv::COLOR_RGBA2RGB);

            auto byte_buffer = builder.CreateVector(mat.data, sizeof(mat.data));
            //
            //
            auto mloc = Dx11::Frame::CreateFrame(builder, byte_buffer);

            builder.Finish(mloc);
            pub.Send(builder, -1);
```

Comment: DirectX uses (pseudo/nano/lightweight) COM. For every COM object that you allocate, you must must myRef->Release(); There's nothing more to it. The best with C++ is to use smart pointers (lots of library provide this: std, ATL, WIL, WRL, and C++/WinRT).

Comment: As mentioned, I tried that to the same end. Maybe I did it wrong, but you just wrap the type in a com pointer and use .get when you need it. Same issue.

Comment: As I said, there's nothing more to Release, so yes, there's 99% changes of you did it wrong. Check errors and activate the debug layer to get more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/using-the-debug-layer-to-test-apps and https://walbourn.github.io/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks/ otherwise there's no way to find your bug w/o a minimal reproducing sample https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I hate to say it, I think I'll just prime 2 frame pools and destroy the class which should remove it with extreme prejudice. Then swap between them every second or so, so I don't get memory ballooning and I don't lose performance. Really MS should make these more robust. My biggest complaint is that the middle apis in c++ suck. Look at ecal and you see a simple API is possible. I don't need chuck and them writing thousands of lines of sample apps, I need better apis